# in C# windows universal app, I need to create a grid and divide it to number of columns and rows. I need to do that in the code, not in the XAML

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

```
            Grid myGrid = new Grid();
        myGrid.Width = 1000;
        myGrid.Height = 1000;
        myGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();
            rd.Height = new GridLength(10);

            ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition();
            cd.Width = new GridLength(10);

            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
            myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);


        }
```

after I ran this code i don't see any change in the app.
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Are you actually adding the `Grid` to the `View`?

Answer (score 0):

In XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="fatherGrid">
</Grid>
```

In C#

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Grid myGrid = new Grid();
        myGrid.Width = 1000;
        myGrid.Height = 1000;
        myGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            RowDefinition rd = new RowDefinition();
            //rd.Height = new GridLength(10);

            ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition();
            //cd.Width = new GridLength(10);

            myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
            myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "Hello";
            Grid.SetRow(tb, i);
            Grid.SetColumn(tb, i);
            myGrid.Children.Add(tb);
        }

        this.fatherGrid.Children.Add(myGrid);

    }
```

Result:
[image]